# Covert CLLocation to PFGeoPoint with Swift

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, parse-platform

Is there an example of the swift implementation of the constructor +geoPointWithLocation?

https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFGeoPoint.html#//api/name/geoPointWithLocation:

current attempt:

```
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    var currentLoc = CLLocationManager()
    currentGeoPoint = PFGeoPoint(geoPointWithLocation(currentLoc))
```

Comment: You don't pass the location itself. Location manager should return you current location in one of its delegate methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used this framework, but... Try `PFGeoPoint(location: currentLoc)`.

Generally, when you have an ObjC factory method call like `+[NSFooBar fooBarWithBaz:]`, it imports as the Swift initializer `init(baz:)`.

Oh, and it looks like you need to actually get a location from your `CLLocationManager`, not just pass the manager to `PFGeoPoint`.

Comment: I thought I needed to use the `geoPointWithLocation` constructor? Not just `PFGeoPoint`. and my current code doesn't generate the actual location?

Comment: Writing `PFGeoPoint(location: currentLoc)` is how you call `geoPointWithLocation` from Swift. But for that to compile, `currentLoc` needs to be a `CLLocation`; in the code you've posted, it's a `CLLocationManager`. Implement the location manager delegate methods to get the current location, then pass that to `PFGeoPoint(location:)`.